# Charlock_Holmes not returning anything in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to use the gem charlock_holmes (https://github.com/brianmario/charlock_holmes) to detect and correct character formatting errors. However, the program doesn't return anything.

My code is:

```
require 'charlock_holmes'
contents = File.read('./myfile.csv')
detection = CharlockHolmes::EncodingDetector.detect(contents)
# => {:encoding => 'UTF-8', :confidence => 100, :type => :text}
```

as specified in the documentation.

When I run this in the directory, I just get nothing at all:

```
user$ ruby detector.rb 
user$
```

Expected behavior is that it returns the detected encoding (and, if desired, can change it as well). I've got all the gems installed, I think, and I've tried under both 1.9.2 and 2.0.0.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or how to find out? I'm afraid I'm new to ruby, but I have tried to do a pretty comprehensive search before asking and have come up blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should put `p detection` in your file `detector.rb`.

Save your code as below :

```
require 'charlock_holmes'
contents = File.read('./myfile.csv')
detection = CharlockHolmes::EncodingDetector.detect(contents)
p detection
```

Now run it as you ran earlier.